# What does this python code of the form foo = bar *\ baz do?

Tags: python

```
    delta = self.cost_derivative(activations[-1], y) * \
        sigmoid_prime_vec(zs[-1])
```

I don't understand at a high level what `* \` as well as the indent before `sigmoid_prime_vec` is called implies. Is it just a multiplication that spans multiple lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` is used to break long line into multiple lines. (line continuation). See [Explicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining).

```
>>> 1 + \
... 2
3
>>>
>>> 1 + \
... 2 + \
... 3
6
```

Instead of `\`, you can use `( ... )`. See [Implicit line joining](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining).

```
>>> (1 +
... 2)
3
```

According to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), Implicit line joining is preferred.

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.

Comment: @algorithmicCoder, Yes, it is.